# Excel Mobile (Office 365) equivalent of CELL("filename")

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I'm trying to create an excel workbook that can work on all platforms including mobile and web. The only problem is the following: I want to use the sheet name in a formula. Is there a way to access that without the use of the CELL("filename") function?

Comment: Cell("filename") does not unfortunatly, no :(

Comment: Is VBA an Option? (I doubt it, if `CELL()` isn't even available).  And yeah, [as of 2017](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_winother-mso_o365b/onedrive-online-excel-and-sheet-names/e261c235-a002-4e17-bf55-fffcf4574372) the Online Excel has only the basic functions. hmm...  Edit: [Another moderator, in 2018](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_o365b/how-to-equate-sheet-name-to-cell-value-in-excel/c99c3584-875b-4be9-8117-f64a7fd2768f) says they can't find other methods to get the sheet name.